# C++ programming conventions regarding class definitions

Tags: c++, coding-style

Learning how to program without any formal IT education, I am fairly oblivious to many common programming conventions. Though nonessential, these details have been bugging me for quite a long time, and I would be relieved to know a more professional opinion about them.

```
class Bar{};
class Foo
{
public:                 //Is [public > protected > private] the usual order?
    Foo();              //Should constructors and destructors be listed before
    void doStuff(void); //..other member functions?
    int publicVariable; //Should data members be kept separate from methods?
private:
    int x_;             //Is there an established order regarding data members?
    bool isReady_;
    Bar bar_;           //Trailing underscore on private class instances?
};
```

Comment: These are pretty much all up to you (or your set coding style guidelines) as long as you're consistent.

Comment: Google around for C++ guidelines and style guides. There is a list [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/other-coding-stds.html) also see [boost's policy](http://www.boost.org/development/header.html) and read through them.

Comment: You can find completely opposite coding conventions... the implementation is the most important part: `private` on top, the implementation is a detail and the important bit is the interface: `public` on top... `protected` is not that commonly used anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most companies [1]  will have "coding standards" that dictate not only how to name variables, classes and functions (e.g. "specific letter at the begginning of member variables" or "upper case first letter in member functions, lowercase for variables"), but also where to place braces (same line, line below, how far in from the think it refers to) and how to name header files in relation to the source files. Quite possibly also "write `if (0 == x)` instead of `if (x == 0)`", and other similar rules.

Any decent company will also have code-reviews, where someone else checks that your code before it goes into a "real production", and the code-reviewer should also be checking the coding standard is being followed.

These coding standard do vary from company to company. But the goal is to make the code consistent within the company. And you'll probably also find some code that was written 10 years ago, and it still works, but it's not following the coding standard, and nobody dares touching it, because it may break! ;)

[1] Or other organisation, group, team, school, etc.